# form_validation->run() returns false Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

My problem is when I click submit the form_validation->run() returns false

Here is my controller

```
public function change_pass()
{
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('new_pass', 'New Password', 'required|matches[cnew_pass]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cnew_pass','Confirm Password','required|matches[new_pass]');

if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
{
die(print_r("Always go here"));
}
}
```

Here is my view.................

```
    <?php echo form_open('tickets/change_pass'); ?>
     <center>
<table>

            <tr>
                <td<label for="new_pass">New Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="new_pass" class="form-control"><?php echo form_error('new_pass');?>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td<label for="cnew_pass">Confirm New Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="cnew_pass" class="form-control"><?php echo form_error('cnew_pass');?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" name="change" class="btn btn-success"> <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">
    </center>
```

Comment: Put your full code of view here.

Comment: Also in your validation rule just remove `matches[new_pass]` for confirm password validation

Comment: matches[cnew_pass] is sufficient no need of matches[new_pass]

Comment: Where is your `form_close()`?

Comment: Did you changed your controller as suggested and checkedcheck wheter you are typing the passwords correctly.

Comment: I think It doesnt need anymore because in other view I dont have form_close().. I think the problem is the matches.. when I remove the matches the codes run.

Comment: thats is what i told you to remove :)

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('new_pass', 'New Password', 'required|matches[cnew_pass]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cnew_pass','Confirm Password','required');

I did..but still not working..

Comment: <td> tag not correctly closed.<td in new password and confirm

Answer (score 2):

hi you have to first load view in separate function.this will be your code.

```
public function index()
    {

        $this->load->helper('form');

        $this->load->view('your view name');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to check that you click to the submit button then the validation

here is the code you need to change in your controller

```
public function change_pass() {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        if ($this->input->post('submit')) {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('new_pass', 'New Password', 'required|matches[cnew_pass]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cnew_pass', 'Confirm Password', 'required|matches[new_pass]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            die(print_r("Always go here"));
        }
        }
        $this->load->view('change_pass');
    }
```

because of not checking is always false in validation 
i think it should help you